# How do you call a method every hour in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, time, resque

I'm using [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) with [Redis](http://redis.io/) to process a background job. I'd like to call the method, Resque.enqueue(MyModel) just one time every hour to do a background task.

For example: Say I have a site that has a 10,000 users. I would like to call this method only 24 times per day; not 10,000 * 24. The example method is below:

```
Resque.enqueue(MyModel)
```

Thank you for your help in advance. I should also mention I prefer to stick with Resque, and not move to Delayed Job. Thank you.

Comment: Infinite while loop, call method first then sleep 3600 seconds?

Comment: How would you dare :) there are dedicated tools for this!

Comment: @apneadiving tbh, in a simple case like this (especially where you need access to an object), I'd be just as likely to do that as I would to set up a cron job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a cron job for this kind of task.

I suggest you use the Whenever gem.

See railscast here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

Comment: I'm watching the railscast #164 and the Whenever gem looks nice. Do you have a lot of good experience with this gem? Any negatives I should consider?

Comment: Nope, it's great and let you schedule whatever you need with a proper periodicity

Comment: This looks like a great gem. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You should really look at Marcel's answer too if you find performance is becoming an issue should you have more than, say, 10-20 tasks running at fairly short intervals.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already using Resque, I would recommend to use one of the many available Resque plugins: [resque-scheduler](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler). Plugs into the Resque UI very nicely as well. Simple setup as explained in the README. Also adds a lot of the missing DelayedJob stuff (delayed execution).

Why I switched from `whenever` to `resque-scheduler`:

- Stays in the app-folder and doesn't mess with your cron file.
- To stop all 'crons' just disable the Resque workers.
- Exceptions are logged to the Resque UI.
- Manual rescheduling via the Resque UI possible.
- In combination with `resque-loner` you prevent double-execution should a job take longer than the span between two executions.
- Still obeys to the priority-system of Resque.
- No additional boot-time (could take up to 60s if your app gets bigger) since it uses Resque's worker-pool.
- One less "tech" used.
- Simple switch: Configuration is done in a cron-like manner.

Comment: +1 because it looks like this would not incur the environment startup time of running a rake test every 5 mins etc.  That's a big win for us, having lots of background tasks.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) which exactly does what you asked and a lot more,it has a pretty good documentation.

you can use some syntax like this:

```
every 3.hours do
    runner "MyModel.some_process"
    rake "my:rake:task"
    command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end
```

install it using:

```
$ gem install whenever
```

or add it to your GemFile:

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

then run:

```
$ cd /apps/my-great-project
$ wheneverize .
```

hope this helps you!